# Setting state using regex

Tags: regex, reactjs

I have the value of a 64 bit encoded image as `Object { photo: "/9j/...Q==" }` but I would like to use regex to only obtain the value inside the " ". Not only this, but I have this value as the value of the state (`this.state.profilePhoto = Object { photo: "/9j/...Q==" }`). I'm trying to use regex to filter out the actual value that I want and replace the state with the new, correct value. This is what I have but it does not seem to work in that it is returning the actual regex expression.

```
const regex = /(.*)/;
const photo = //some get request
this.setState({ profilePhoto: photo});
this.setState({profilePhoto: regex});
```

When I log the output of profilePhoto's state to the console, I get `/(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/;` instead of the number inside the quotes.

Comment: @JacobN I'm using react

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet, you haven't actually applied the RegEx to the value of `photo`. If `photo` were a string, you would want to modify the above to something like:

```
const regex = /(.*)/;
const photo = //some get request
const filteredValue = photo.match(regex)
this.setState({ profilePhoto: filteredValue });
```

That said, in your question it seems like photo is just an Object and you simply want the value of the key `photo` inside of it? If you just want photo to be the string instead of an object, you would use:

```
const photo = //some get request
// Pull the photo key from the photo Object, renaming to photoString
const { photo: photoString } = photo
this.setState({ profilePhoto: photoString });
```

References:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: For your second suggestion, I wuold still need to filter out the quotes correct?

Comment: Also, match returns an array, which I do not want

Comment: In the second suggestion, you would have a string which appears in the console with quotes yes but isn't part of the value. i.e. if you ran `const substring = photoString.substring(1, yourString.length-1);` you'd just be cutting off the "/" and "=" characters.

Comment: Match returns an array of matches, yes. In this case, you'd have a single match.
`const filteredValue = photo.match(regex)[0]`